# What does "Let's be in touch {TIME}" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms, responses

In a job hunt email a person said that is not looking for someone right now, *Let's be in touch summer 2017.*

What does he mean and how can I say to him that I would like to speak more closely to the date?

Comment: What do you mean "more closely to the date"? What date are you talking about? Do you mean that you want to be in touch before summer 2017?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you tried to look up *touch*, but the sentence still didn't make sense.

The idiom in this case is *be in touch*.

> *be in touch*
>
> - to have regular communication with someone by telephone, letter etc. (usually + with ) [[1.]](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+in+touch)
> - to see, speak to, or write to someone [[2.]](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/in-touch-with-someone)

So *let's be in touch summer 2017* essentially means *let's talk in summer 2017*.

Well, if it's job related, and you want to say that you will speak around summer 2017, then you could say

1. We'll be in touch.
2. I have your number/email/info/etc.
3. I look forward to to speaking with you again.
4. I will (talk to you)/(contact you) then.

Option 2. implies that you will contact this person in the future.